# Getting all characters from NSFont

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsfont

I have custom `NSFont` (FontAwesome) and I would like to get all characters from this font. I've looked through all the documentation about fonts, but can't find anything do display it all.

Any ideas how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to get all characters, you can use [`-coveredCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000382-DontLinkElementID_22).

Otherwise, esp. if you want to get the glyph shapes, precise your Q. This will be a longer A.